# Toggle state of multiple elements by clicking one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following structure on a page:

```
<div class="mycontainer">
  <div class="mysubclass">
    <div class="myheader">header 1</div>
    <div class="mycontent">content 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mysubclass">
    <div class="myheader">header 2</div>
    <div class="mycontent">content 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mysubclass">
    <div class="myheader">header 3</div>
    <div class="mycontent">content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to get the following behaviour:
Right after page load all of them are closed. When I click on the first **mysubclass**, its **myheader** and **mycontent** should get additional class active. When I click on it again it should be removed. All the other elements shouldn't become an active class.
When I klick on first **mysubclass**, its **myheader** and **mycontent** should get additional class active again. When I click a second **mysubclass**, the active classes should be removed from the first **mysubclass** and added to the elements of the second (clicked) **mysubclass**.

In fact I need to simulate opening and closing elements with content, so when it's closed, content is not visible, and when I cklick on an element it gets class **active** and content is shown.

My JQuery code is following:

```
$(".mysubclass").click(function(e) {

  if ($(".myheader").hasClass("activ") && $(".mycontent").hasClass("activ")) {
    $(".myheader").removeClass("activ");
    $(".mycontent").removeClass("activ");
  } else {
    $(".myheader").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(".mycontent").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(".myheader").addClass("active");
    $(".mycontent").addClass("active");
  }
});
```

How can I get this behaviour working without changing html code?
Here is my example of this problem: [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/middleendian/po3Lj3rm/9/) .

Comment: if they are all closed how do you click on them?

Comment: Like in my JSFiddle example, clicking on mysubclass. I added JQery code here aswell

Comment: you said `Right after page load all of them are closed` what are you referring to

Comment: Ah ok I see, none of them has class active. Active should be added only after clicking a specific element (mysubclass)

Comment: and so they should be hidden without class `active`?

Comment: only the content should be hidden

Comment: In your question you state `When I click on the first mysubclass, its myheader and mycontent should get additional class active` twice, should the second one be about the second mysubclass?

Comment: Yes, first I click on first `mysubclass` with content1, `myheader` and `mycontent` should get `activ` class. When I click the same (first) `mysubclass` again, `active` should be removed. Then I click on first `mysubclass` again (it's already a third click), `myheader` and `mycontent` should get `active` again. Then I click second `mysubclass`, class `active` should be romeved from the first one and added to second `myheader` and  `mycontent`. I hope this is better to understand what I mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
 $(".mysubclass").click(function(e) { 
   if ($(this).find(".myheader").hasClass("active") && $(this).find(".mycontent").hasClass("active")) {

    $(this).find(".myheader").removeClass("active");
    $(this).find(".mycontent").removeClass("active");
} else {
    $(".mycontainer .active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).find(".myheader").addClass("active");
    $(this).find(".mycontent").addClass("active");
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/po3Lj3rm/13/

Comment: clicking the 1st then 2nd has both open/active, clicking the second one should make it the only one active

Comment: Oh ok, I will change that

Comment: if you add `$('div').removeClass('active');` to the `else` it should work

Comment: Thank you guys, this works indeed with `$('div').removeClass('active');`
Though removing `activ` from all divs with this code may cause bigger problems if there're other `active` classes in the project :) But as long as `activ` is present only for a certain element, it works just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```js
$('.mysubclass').on('click', function() {
  $('.myheader').not($(this).find('.myheader')).removeClass('active');
  $('.mycontent').not($(this).find('.mycontent')).removeClass('active');

  if (!$(this).find('.mycontent').hasClass("active")) {
    $(this).find('.mycontent').addClass('active');
    $(this).find('.myheader').addClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).find('.mycontent').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.myheader').removeClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.mycontainer {
  padding: 10px;
}
.mysubclass {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.myheader {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff0000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.mycontent {
  height: 80px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mycontainer">
  <div class="mysubclass">
    <div class="myheader">header 1</div>
    <div class="mycontent">content 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mysubclass">
    <div class="myheader">header 2</div>
    <div class="mycontent">content 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mysubclass">
    <div class="myheader">header 3</div>
    <div class="mycontent">content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With Class `active` - [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/po3Lj3rm/17/) here

Without class `active` - [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/po3Lj3rm/15/) here

Comment: thank you for your help, it works indeed, but your solution doesn't include `active` classes as I need them. But this is actually a very great solution for a similar use-case!

Comment: @middleendian , I have update the answer , code including the class `active`